# Angularjs template fails to work

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing, angularjs-templates

I am working on an app about routing, my code:

```
//HTML, I passed a 'test' into routing
<a href="#details/test">Test</a>
<div data-ng-view=""></div>

//Template
<h1>{{res}}</h1>

//Angularjs
var app = angular.module("dictApp", ['ngRoute']);

app.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
    when('/details/:test', {
        templateUrl: 'template.html', 
        controller: 'testCtrl'
    });
}]);

app.controller('testCtrl', function ($scope, $routeProvider) {
    $scope.res = $routeProvider.test;
});

//The template is displayed as
{{res}}
```

The template page should display 'test', but I don't know why it didn't work.

Thansk in advance.

Answer (score 1):

'test' parameter should be available in $routeParams.

```
app.controller('testCtrl', function ($scope, $routeParams) {
    $scope.res = $routeParams.test;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The service that exposes the route parameters is `$routeParams`. `$routeProvider` is the provider used to configure the routes in the app like the one you have done in your code using `.when` method as well

You need to inject `$routeParams` and use it instead of `$routeProvider`

```
app.controller('testCtrl', function ($scope, $routeParams) {
  $scope.res = $routeParams.test;
});
```